# The script code works fine in firefox and internet explorer but not in google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

This is my html and scripting code for the show hide div.not working in google chrome but it is working fine in firefox and ie8 what can i do now?? kindly check the code here i have shared. hide(); show(); functions are not working properly.

```
   <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .tab-container /* this is the css code for the tabs*/
    {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    //border:1px solid #147D36;
    //border-left:4px solid #147D36;    
    margin-left:1.5%;
    margin-right:1.5%;
     }

    .tab-text /* this is the div for the text that is coming on hover*/
     {
    width:97%;
    margin-left:3%;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#1B6298;
    margin-top:-65px;
    z-index:999999;
    /*display:none;*/
     }
     .tab-title/* this is the div for the text title that is coming on hover*/
     {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    padding-top:17px;
     }
    .tab-content/* this is the div for the text content that is coming on hover*/
     {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
     }

    </style>
      <!--this is my html code-->
     <div class="tab-container">
     <img src="images/ourmission.png" width="100%">
     <div class="tab-text">
     <div class="tab-title">Our Mission</div>
     <div class="tab-content">read more</div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-container">
     <img src="images/ourfinincial.png" width="100%">
     <div class="tab-text">
     <div class="tab-title">Our Financial</div>
     <div class="tab-content">read more</div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-container">
     <img src="images/ourgoals.png" width="100%">
     <div class="tab-text">
     <div class="tab-title">Our Team</div>
     <div class="tab-content">read more</div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <script>
    /*jquery code for the show and hide function on hover-scripting code */
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.tab-text').hide();
     $('.tab-container').hover(function() {
     $(this).find('.tab-text').show();
     }, function() {
     $('.tab-text').hide();
     });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: HTML and CSS code please? can you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq46A/1/

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-text').hide();

    $('.tab-container').hover(function() {
        $('.tab-text').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.tab-text').hide();
    });

});
```

- You don't need 2 `$(document).ready();`
- Instead of `$(this).find...` use `$('.tab-text')`

Comment: don't assume... he could have multiple tab containers and therefore multiple tab texts taht he doesn't want all shown or hidden at once

Comment: @Derek That's exactly what I am doing. I am answering based on the given information.

Comment: @user3622726 you need to be more constructive than "it's not working". What exactly is not working for you? The demo, your code, or something else?

Comment: there are multiple tab-text and tab-container thats why i have used the find() function..But after removing 2nd ready() function its not working on google chrome..and it is working fine in ff and ie8

Comment: If you are using `.find()` we need to see the HTML structure. Also, do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's interesting. I have optimized your fiddle and ironically enough it works for all browsers which i've tested this function except chrome. At chrome, it works only for the first time. But after it, it fails to display the element nicely. Here below is a snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hold curr display
    var currText = null;
    // hide all tabs
    // $('.tab-text').hide();

    // action when hovering
    $('.tab-container').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            currText = $(this).find('.tab-text');
            currText.show(); // doesn't work perfectly in chrome after hide() call
        }, function(){
            currText.hide(); 
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7dKT/3/)

What i have done is assigned the `.hover()` function to each found div with class `tab-container`. And i have used a variable `currText` to store the found element there when hovering the parent div that you don't have to redo the search for the right element.

Also, i have adapted the HTML structure in proper format. (fe `/` missing in `<img>`-tag).
Besides that, the elements which are hidden by default is done by CSS.

I'm going to post this answer now, to inform you that the `show()` doesn't work well after using the `hide()` function. I'm going to find out if it's a bug and that it can be solved.

### UPDATE 1

When trying to accomplish the same in CSS only, it has the same behavior as the above script. But when looking to the CSS, i found out that chrome has issues with your floating elements.

If i float your image to the left, using the CSS here below, the script **works fine**.

```
.tab-container img {
    float: left;
}
```

Certainly Chrome has issues with your multiple floating CSS values. I also notice two floats, one to left, then one to right for the `.tab-content` selector.

Please check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7dKT/8/) in chrome and FF. Now it works as expected after adding the above CSS rule. I'm going to submit a bug report to chrome because this as a non-conforming behavior at chrome's end.

I hope that this solves your issue.

Comment: thank u its working f9 now after addding float:left to <img> tag